# Writing $(1+i)^{18}$ in the form $a+bi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How do I write

$ (1+i)^{18}$ in the form $a+bi$? It is not a good method to simply expand it? Is there something else I can employ?

Comment: Are you familiar with [De_Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)?

Comment: Are you familiar with the polar form of a complex number?

Comment: At worst you could try the binomial theorem...

Answer (score 11):

I would say

$(1+i)^{18}=((1+i)^2)^9=(2i)^9=512i^9=512i$

Answer (score 3):

Note that the complex number $1+i$ can be written as $\sqrt{2}\left(\cos \frac{\pi}{4} + i \sin  \frac{\pi}{4} \right)$. This is called the "[polar form](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/imaginary-and-complex-numbers/multiplying-and-dividing-complex-numbers-in-polar-form/a/complex-number-polar-form-review)" of a complex number, as opposed to the "rectangular" or cartesian representation, which has the form $a+ib$.

Khan Academy summarizes the polar form of a complex number as follows.

> The polar form of complex numbers emphasizes their graphical attributes: the *absolute value* (the distance of the number from the origin in the complex plane) and the *angle* (the angle that the number forms with the positive Real axis). These are also called the *modulus* and *argument*, respectively.

Once we have converted a complex number into a polar representation, we can easily apply [De Moivre's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) to raise it to an arbitrary exponent:
$$\left[r\left(\cos x + i \sin x\right)\right]^n = r^n \left(\cos (nx) + i \sin (nx)\right)$$

In your case,

\begin{align}
(1+i)^{18} &= \left[\sqrt{2}\left(\cos \frac{\pi}{4} + i \sin  \frac{\pi}{4} \right)\right]^{18} =2^{18/2} \left(\cos \frac{18\pi}{4} + i \sin  \frac{18\pi}{4} \right)\\
 &= 512\left( \cos \frac{\pi}{2} + i\sin \frac{\pi}{2} \right) = 512(0+i) =512i
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

To express $z=1+i$ in the form of $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$, we need to calculate the absolute value $r$ and argument $\theta$

$$\mbox{Absolute value: }r=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$$
$$\mbox{Argument: }\theta=\arctan\dfrac11=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

Now, by using [DeMoiver's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), we get
$$z^{18}=\left[\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\sin\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)\right]^{18}$$
$$=2^{18/2} \left(\cos \frac{18\pi}{4} + i \sin  \frac{18\pi}{4} \right)$$
$$=512\left(\cos\dfrac{\pi}{2}+i\sin\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
$$=512i$$
Therefore, $(1+i)^{18}=512i$